# Raspberry Pi 4B not discoverable

Tags: pi-4, ssh, ethernet, connection

Just bought a new Raspberry Pi 4B, and im installing this device with the recommended OS(64b) using the Raspberry Pi Imager. Im using LAN cable from my router for internet connection.

The issue is, i can ping my router, 1.1.1.1, or google.com, but i can't ping this device with my laptop or other device, although they are connected with the same network. Nor, i can't ping my laptop or other devices with this Raspberry Pi.

Im also sure that ive pinged the right IP address, which i can see the them from the router toplogy, but i cant discover this Raspberry Pi with IP scanner software.

Am i missing something here? Maybe i missed something on the config file? or its just my router that needs to be configured? Thanks in advance

Comment: is the pi wireless or wired?

Comment: I don't know, but you may have chosen an ***inappropriate*** IP address for your router: `1.1.1.1`.  That address is a *"public"* IP address.  ***OTOH*** it could be that your question is written in a confusing way. I'd suggest you edit your question to help clarify.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your Raspberry Pi is configured to obtain an IP address dynamically (via DHCP) from your router. Make sure that the LAN cable is securely connected to both your Raspberry Pi and the router. Also, check the LED indicators on the Raspberry Pi's Ethernet port to confirm a stable connection.